# Is it a good idea to create a TcpListener from Observables?

Tags: f#, observable, tcplistener

I've been having fun playing around with the FSharp.Control.Reactive library while trying to learn some of the applications for reactive programming. Listening for a client using the .NET TcpListener class is a reactive process so I decided to create a server (in loose terms) in F# using Observables. My test use case is a single client connection from an astronomy program (Stellarium) that sends the celestial coordinates of stars in a 20 byte tcp socket stream. The code snippet I have below works but is it a good idea, or practical in anyway, to use Observables to subscribe to a TcpListener and any eventual client streams that connect? What would be the advantage or disadvantage?

```
open System
open System.Net
open System.Net.Sockets
open System.Threading
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Reactive.Concurrency
open System.Reactive.Disposables
open FSharp.Control.Reactive.Builders
open FSharp.Control.Reactive.Observable
open FSharp.Control.Reactive.Disposables

type TcpListener with
    member l.AcceptClientAsync = async {
        let! client = Async.AwaitTask <| l.AcceptSocketAsync()
        return client
    }

let readCoordinates(coords : byte[]) =
    let raInt = BitConverter.ToUInt32(coords, 12)
    let decInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(coords, 16)

    let ra_h = float raInt * 12.0 / 2147483648.0
    let dec_h = float decInt * 90.0 / 1073741824.0

    if (coords.Length > 0) then
        Some (ra_h, dec_h)
    else
        None

let listen() = 
    let ipAddr = IPAddress.Any
    let endpoint = IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 10001)
    let listener = TcpListener(endpoint)

    listener.Start()

    observe.While ((fun () -> true), ofAsync(listener.AcceptClientAsync))
    |> bind( (fun socket -> observe.Yield(new NetworkStream(socket))) )
    |> bind(fun stream -> observe.While( (fun _ -> true), ofAsync(stream.AsyncRead(20)) ))
    |> map (fun bytes -> readCoordinates bytes)


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    listen()
    |> subscribe (fun coords -> printfn "Target Coordinates %A" coords)
    |> ignore


    printfn "Hit enter to continue"
    Console.Read() |> ignore

    0
```